# Win CE Calendar :Add Appointment ::Need help :appointment:save->E_outofmemory

Tags: windows, windows-ce

I am trying to add appointment to calendar (using pimstore.lib n .h) using win ce...I am trying as follows:
        CoCreateInstance(CLSID_Application, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, 
            IID_IPOutlookApp, reinterpret_cast(&polApp))
    polApp->Logon(NULL);
        polApp->CreateItem(olAppointmentItem, (IDispatch**)&pAppt);
        HRESULT hr = polApp->GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar, &pFolder);
        hr = pFolder->get_Items(&pItems);
        hr = pItems->Add((IDispatch**)&pAppt);
        hr = pAppt->Save();
        save giving me outofmemory exception.....May i know the reason plz.....

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have PIM on Windows CE? I can't find support for that on MSDN.

As far as I know only Windows Mobile has Outlook from MS.

Can you post links to the documentation you are using?

Comment: thanks for reply..I ma referring 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa913446.aspx

only save thing is getting exception....but prior steps getting S_OK
success

Comment: OK. I now saw that WinCE supports POOM. But, I can't help - sorry. Thanks for the link.